# What is the value of $\measuredangle x ~if~ \overset{\LARGE\frown}{DE} = 40^\circ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

For reference:

[image]

My progress:

[image]

$\measuredangle DIE = 360 - 180 - 40 = 140^\circ\\\triangle ADE~(isosceles) \implies \measuredangle ADE = \measuredangle AED=\frac{140}{2}=70^\circ$

some property is missing in the quadrilateral or triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be a center of the third circle.

Thus, $B$, $G$ and $F$ are placed on the same line, $BG=BD$ and $FG=FE$.

Id est, $$x=\measuredangle DGB+\measuredangle EGF=\frac{1}{2}\left(\measuredangle ABF+\measuredangle AFB\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot140^{\circ}=70^{\circ}.$$

Comment: @Michael..great..can $explain x=\measuredangle DGB+\measuredangle EGF=\frac{1}{2}\left(\measuredangle ABF+\measuredangle AFB\right)$

Comment: @Michael, I do not see B in the figure. where is it?

Comment: @sirous  "Let $B$ be a center of the third circle"

Comment: @peta arantes Because $\measuredangle ABF=\measuredangle DGB+\measuredangle GDB=2\measuredangle DGB.$

Comment: @Michael...understood..exterior angle of a triangle GDB and EGF

Comment: @sirous...I updated the drawing